# Setting url for the web application

Tags: html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am creating website from a scratch. I am using another web app project for the reference.

Now the project I debug works on the particular url in my local system. I need to set another url for the new website.

How to set that?  Any help experts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click your project > properties > Tab: Web > Scroll to servers section.

There you can define to use IIS, IIS Express etc and you can also set the URL you want to use for debugging.

Comment: when i right click on solution i can see common properties & configuration properties

Comment: I found it. Thanks :) So i can set any url in that? i mean the url can be any random url created by me ?

Comment: If you are debugging locally, it should point to your local machine such as http://localhost/blablabla or http://127.0.0.1/blablabla or your IP.